# php curl long polling

Tags: php, curl

Is long polling allowed on php curl? How can I make a long polling request? I am currently using ajax to call a php file which makes a get call, but I want to do long polling is there anything I could do?

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://testcURL.com/?item1=value&item2=value2',
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
```

How can I modify for long polling? I am new to this so any help is appreciated

Comment: Long polling makes more sense between browser and the server, not server to server. You may set a really high timeout value, but you also have to make sure that the communication between the client and server doesn't timeout either.

Comment: I am mostly using php curl as a "proxy" so I can communicate with my web service. Moreover, I am making a long polling request from my browser (port 80) to my service located in tomcat (port 7555) so I need something to get over without setting cross domain headers on the webserivce

Comment: Would you consider Server Side Events (SSE) or WebSocket instead?

Comment: I could consider but I was wondering if php curl would be easier. which of the two (WS or SSE) would you recommend for a messaging client?